# Show PHP getter value in input type name in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to show product value in input type after getting it from getters:

Code:

```
    $domain =  'woocommerce';
        global $product;
    
    // Getters
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
   printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="price" value="$price" required="true" type="number"/><br>', __( 'Fixed price:', $domain ) );
```

Comment: Yes, value="$price" not working. Not showing the price in the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf( '<label>%s</label><input name="price" value="%.02f" required="true" type="number"/><br>', __( 'Fixed price:', $domain ), $price );
```

Pass the float value to the [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function as %f placeholder

Comment: I have just one question, this text field shows value in decimal numbers. For example, it shows price in $35.00, I'm calculating this price to show final price, and the calculator returns wrong answer.

Is there any way to remove this decimal numbers? Show $35 instead of $35.00

Comment: Replace `%.02f` to `%d`